# derivative of matrix equation with elementwise term

Tags: matrices, derivatives

D, S, L are $M \times M$ matrix, $D_{ij}$ and $L_{ij}$ is the element of matrix D and L. D and S is known, L is unknow. how to calculate the derivative of the equation list below.

$${ { f(L)=\left\| D-S-L \right\|  }_{ F }^{ 2 } }+\sum _{ i }^{ M }{ \sum _{ j }^{ M }{ \log { \left( { D }_{ ij }-{ L }_{ ij } \right)  }  }  } $$

Answer (score 1):

When a scalar function $f(x)$ is applied element-wise to a matrix argument $X$, the differential is given by $$df=f'(X)\circ dX$$ where $f'$ is the normal scalar derivative and $\circ$ represents the Hadamard product.

Using this result, we can write your function in terms of the Hadamard ($\circ$) and Frobenius (:) products and find its differential
$$\eqalign{
 f &= (L+S-D):(L+S-D) + 1:{\log}(D-L) \cr\cr
 df &= 2(L+S-D):dL + 1:d{\log}(D-L) \cr
    &= 2(L+S-D):dL + 1:\frac{1}{D-L}\circ(-dL)  \cr
    &= 2(L+S-D):dL + \frac{1}{L-D}:dL  \cr
    &= \bigg[2(L+S-D) + \frac{1}{L-D}\bigg]:dL  \cr
}$$
Since $df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial L}:dL,\,$ the gradient is
$$\eqalign{
  \frac{\partial f}{\partial L} &= 2(L+S-D) + \frac{1}{L-D} \cr
}$$
where $\frac{1}{X}$ represents Hadamard division of a matrix of all ones $1$ by the matrix $X$ (the matrices have the same dimensions).

Comment: Thanks for your help! One more question, where could I learn those knowledge, I can't find it in my convex optimization book.